# Stuttering/frame skipping on Ubuntu 22.04 / 23.04

Tags: 22.04, graphics, performance, system, 23.04

For a few months now (maybe 6 months, I'm not exactly sure when it started) I've been experiencing persistent stuttering at random intervals. It doesn't bother me much for general use but it is really disruptive when playing precise action games such as fighting games. It happens even when nothing heavy is running (no Steam, browser, etc), for example if I open a terminal and hold 'a' I can see it skip frames now and then.

My setup has 1 NVMe SSD drive which is where the main system is installed(previously 22.04. I've since updated to 23.04 as a "hail Mary" to try to fix it, with no success) and an sda HDD drive with 20.10, which I mostly just use for storage.

At first I thought it might be an NVIDIA issue, so I messed around, trying different drivers, but nothing changed. So I thought it might be some random daemon running in the background that could be causing performance issues, for example I used to have AppImageLauncher to run appimages as if they were native installs. I removed that, as well as some other ones that weren't essential. I tried freeing up disk space as well.

System Monitor doesn't show unusual RAM usage, although CPU cores have some spikes sometimes.

Here's the funny thing though: the 20.10 on my sda drive does not have this issue. It runs smoothly (even though many packages there are not updated).
I'm thinking this might be some issue that has accumulated over time with use or something that broke and was not properly fixed at some point, but I still have no idea what it could be or where to look.

My current setup: https://pastebin.com/raw/4xkfavGh

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic 
Packages: 2602 (dpkg), 14 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 44.3 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-viridian-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru-viridian [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT (12) @ 3.800 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 
Memory: 6179MiB / 15908MiB

File Systems:
̈NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   513M  0 part 
└─sda3        8:3    0 446,6G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 232,4G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
```

Comment: Well uh... it seems like the problem has gone away on its own now for some reason.